# OWL Carousel or Flickity? Which one is better?

Tags: performance, slider, carousel, owl-carousel, flickity

I've been searching online to which library to use, If there's any difference, maybe one is better for perfomance but offers fewer options.

I've found some information but didn't go deep into these questions. Can someone tell me if there's any difference between them? Or which one would you recomend?